# Icon file is not opening after the app been published

Tags: c#, .net, azure

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/"), "mainImage.bmp"));
        
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    Icon point = new Icon(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/"), "favicon.ico"));
    g.DrawIcon(point, 10, 10); // here is the error
    // FYI: point.ToBitmap() also would give same error
}
```

I open an icon and draw it onto bitmap. Works well locally but doesn't work on the Azure site after publishing.

> Error: "Parameter is not valid". The `point.Width` and `point.Height` are zeros at that point (though equal to 16 locally). The icon path is correct and it is displayed by the URL "/Content/Images/favicon.ico".

Comment: `System.Drawing` is a wrapper around GDI/GDI+ which does not always work reliably in headless scenarios (such as ASP.NET). Have you tried using the Azure step-through debugger and interrogated `point` in detail?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't call an `Icon` instance `point` as it could be confused with an actual `Point` instance.

Comment: Also, how are you creating your `Graphics` instance? Please post more code.

Comment: @Dai thank you for response. I updated my post due to your question.